# Ошибка run-time check failure #2 Stack around the variable 'N' was corrupted

Tags: c++, runtime

Программа работает, но в конце выдает эту ошибку:

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'N' was corrupted.

Как решить и что это за ошибка?

```
//Определить, является ли шестизначное число "счастливым"

#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    int N[6]; // шестизначное число

    for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
    {
        cout << "Введите " << i << " цифру шестизначного числа\n";
        cin >> N[i];

        if (N[i] < 0 || N[i] > 9 || N[1] == 0 ) {
            cout << "Ошибка!\n";
            return 1;
        }
    }

    system("cls");

    if (N[1] + N[2] + N[3] == N[4] + N[5] + N[6]) {
        cout << "\nВаше число ";
        for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
        {
            cout << N[i];
        }
        cout << " является счастливым!\n\n";
    }
    else if (N[1] + N[2] + N[3] != N[4] + N[5] + N[6]) {
        cout << "\nВаше число ";
        for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
        {
            cout << N[i];
        }
        cout << " не является счастливым :(\n\n";
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int N[6]; // шестизначное число

for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
```

В языке C++ нумерация элементов массивов начинается с нуля, т.е. здесь

```
int N[6];
```

определен массив с элементами `N[0]`,`N[1]`,`N[2]`,`N[3]`,`N[4]`,`N[5]`.

Вы пытаетесь работать с элементом `N[6]`, чем портите все впечатление от программы :) наряду с порчей памяти...

Comment: выходит надо увеличить размер массива на 1 элемент? thanks

Comment: Надо использовать элементы начиная с нулевого... `for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)`, `if (N[0] + N[1] + N[2] == N[3] + N[4] + N[5]) {` и так далее...